# weak_import generates a linker error

Tags: c++, macos, linker, clang

Why doesn't the code below link when compiling under OSX 10.8? And how can I make it link so that it can work across 10.8 and 10.9? I'm using clang++ 5.1.

```
// MyFile.cc
// Compile with: clang++ MyFile.cc -framework ApplicationServices

#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" CFStringRef kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt __attribute__ ((weak_import));
extern "C" Boolean AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions (CFDictionaryRef options) __attribute__ ((weak_import));

static bool IsSupported (void)
{
    return AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions ?
        AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions (NULL):
        AXAPIEnabled() || AXIsProcessTrusted();
}

int main (void)
{
    std::cout << (IsSupported() ? "SUPPORTED\n" : "NOT SUPPORTED\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** Everything works in 10.9 and the binary works in 10.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak linking still requires linking. The library or framework to which you link still has to define the symbol. In the 10.8 SDK, the ApplicationServices framework doesn't have the `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions` symbol defined.

I can think of at least two reasons that the symbol has to be defined by the library. First, to detect errors, such as if you had a typo in the symbol name in your code. You want the linker to be able to inform you that the symbol will never be available. Second (and probably more important), because of the two-level namespace feature of the linker and dynamic loader. For a symbol provided by a dynamic library or framework, the linker records not just the symbol name but also the library or framework from which it was resolved. At load time, the symbol is matched against both. This allows two dynamic libraries to provide the same symbol without risk of collision or incorrect binding.

If you want to build against the 10.8 SDK and still conditionally use `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions()`, you will need to use dynamic loading. You would use `dlopen()` to open /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/ApplicationServices and then use `dlsym()` to get the pointer to the function. Check that the pointer is not `NULL`, cast it to the proper type, and then you can call the function it points to.

```
static bool IsSupported (void)
{
    static Boolean (*pAXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions)(CFDictionaryRef options);

    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        void* handle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/ApplicationServices", 0);
        if (handle)
            pAXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions = dlsym(handle, "AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions");
    };

    return pAXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions ?
        pAXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions (NULL):
        AXAPIEnabled() || AXIsProcessTrusted();
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm a Windows developer and we do this all the time. The documentation confused me a bit because I thought weak linking would just do this for me automatically.